# Outbound link tracking for a specific url only

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I create a trigger with the following configuration:

1. Choose Event: Click
2. Configure Trigger:
   Targets Just Links
   Wait for Tags enable
   Max wait time 2000 milliseconds
   Check Validation
3. Enable When:
   Page URL matches RegEx .*
4. Fire On:
   Click URL equals www.linkoutbound.com

If I fire this trigger for all page it works but when I include only the one outbound link which I want it is not working properly.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't get it - to me it looks like you are confusing Page Url and Click Url (Page Url should be set to all pages so that all pages are tagged with an event handler for the click url).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your trigger:
[image]

You don't need check validation and wait time. Use "Element URL" as your fire rule. Also note, if the link is a button for example, instead of regular link - you should use All Elements instead of Just Links.

When your trigger is ready - just make a tag type Event, with "Fire on" rule - Click -> the name of the trigger you created.

Fill the Category/Action/Label fields as you wish (for example Category - Outbound Clicks; Action: Clicked on {{element url}}, Label - Clicked on page: {{url}})

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your tag and trigger configurations?

Comment: The problem seems to be your tag. You should use Google Analytics Tag > Universal Analytics. Set track Type to Event; Tracking ID should be your Google Analytics UA code (UA-XXXX), the Category/Action/Label as described above. Fire it on the same trigger and you'll be good to go. You will see the link clicks in GA under Behaviour > Events. You can also check Real Time > Events to make sure the event is working. 
Just from curiosity - what exactly is the content of the custom HTML tag you made?